# Directing PyCharm to Python 3.3 interpreter?

Tags: python, macos, pycharm

I'm not sure why I'm having so much trouble with this.  I'm on OS X 10.7, and I installed Python with default settings and ran the .command file included.

I just want to get PyCharm working with Python 3.3, but I can't seem to find a working interpreter.  The only one I can find loads instantly (gives 'distribute' and 'setuptools' packages) and gives me 'some skeletons failed to generate' errors.  If I choose one of the 2.7 interpreters it loads for a while but I still get a similar error.  I also get some issue with Python packaging tools not being found (usually it's 'pip').

I've searched for a long time but can't find a solution.

Comment: how did you install Python 3.3 ?

Comment: @yanjost I just ran the mpkg file in the disk image downloaded from python.org

Comment: can you provide more info on your post about the error you're receiving? also, update the path for python you're trying to use... this may be your problem, you need it to point to the python binary folder

Comment: "Python packaging tool 'pip' not found. Install 'pip' or create new VirtualEnv"

This is listed in preferences, highlighted in yellow, not sure how important it is though (it included more than just 'pip' before, but not anymore).  

I'm suddenly not getting the skeleton errors anymore as well (again, it's not exactly an error, but it's clear it's not working properly).

Where is the python binary folder?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

PyCharm detects Python 3.3 path automatically for the Python installed from http://python.org `mpkg` installer:

[image: Path]

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3
```

Once you add this interpreter to PyCharm, install the package management tools (click on the **Install 'distribute'**, then click on **Install 'pip'**):

[image: pip]

Upgrade pip to the latest version using the <kbd>Upgrade</kbd> button (distribute upgrade will fail).

Now you can install packages with the <kbd>Install</kbd> button, for example `Django` can be installed from the Interpreters dialog in PyCharm:

[image: Django]

If you have problems with code completion, try `File` | `Invalidate Caches`, restart PyCharm and wait until indexing is finished. For me it worked fine out of the box:

[image: code completion works]

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't able to get it working at the time, but I was already planning on reformatting that week and I got it working fine on a fresh OS install.

Answer (score 5):

Python 3.3 now uses a new virtualenv mechanism called venv.

You can create one of these environments using:

```
pyvenv myprojectname
```

PyCharm 3.0 does not handle these correctly. The old virtualenv system copied python binaries into the environment, while venv creates symbolic links to the `python3.3` binary instead. PyCharm tries to resolve all these symbolic links, until it finds a real file. This results in it ignoring your virtual environment and using the global environment instead.

To work around this bug, you can copy the `python3.3` binary into your environment's `bin` folder and then add this as the project's interpreter in PyCharm.