# PyCharm Unresolved reference 'print'

Tags: python, pycharm

I started to learn python language, and decided to try out PyCharm IDE, which looks really nice. But, whenever I write print it says "Unresolved reference 'print'". I can run the program, but this red-underline is really annoying. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 118):

I have had the same problem as you, even though I configured Python 3.4.0 as the project's interpreter and all `print`'s in the code were Python 3 compliant function calls.

I got it sorted out by doing this in PyCharm:

> File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Invalidate and Restart

Comment: PyCharm was not resolving open() which is a Python built-in function. This fixed the problem for me. Thanks, I'm sure this saved me a ton of time.

Comment: I can confirm this solution helps even today's version 2016.3. Setting everything right in the project settings and then doing a cache clear helped the IDE get back to correctly identifying basic parts of the language. I am using Pyenv with virtualenv plugin, just to clarify details.

Comment: Worked for about 10 seconds it appears to be a python 2 vs python 3 issue guess they didn't want to keep it up to date :|

Comment: This worked today for pycharm 2023.2.1 not resolving print()

Comment: Still works in IDEA 2023.3.2

Answer (score 6):

If you're in PyCharm and you're getting "Unresolved reference xrange" it's because xrange was removed in Python 3. Range takes over its functionality now. Was working on fast string concat from here:

https://waymoot.org/home/python_string/

And credit for the answer is from /r/learnpython:

https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/2udj3s/pycharm_issue/

Answer (score 4):

This could be related to the version of python you are using. Under python 2.x `print` is a statement:

```
print "hello world"
```

Under python 3, `print` is now a function call:

```
print("hello world")
```

Comment: I'm using python latest version 3.4, and I'm using braces, but still experiencing same error..

Comment: Installed python versions are very platform dependent, most linuxes and mac os use python 2.x for system functionality. The user can then install python 3.x if required, this means there are multiple versions installed, more info about selecting versions in pycharm, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988363/directing-pycharm-to-python-3-3-interpreter

Answer (score 3):

Same problem, I deleted the **.idea** and **__pycache__** directories in the project directory and everything was fine :)

Answer (score 2):

Just delete .idea folder from your project directory.