# Getting "unresolved reference: print" in pycharm community version 2016.1.4

Tags: python, pycharm

I have already tried "invalidate cache and restart" [(as found here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738455/pycharm-unresolved-reference-print).

And I have already tried turning on "collect run-time types for information for code insight" [(as found here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689183/why-does-pycharm-give-unresolved-reference-errors-on-some-numpy-imports).

So I decided to simply remove the error by "ignore unresolved reference" on the print() statements that were complaining (I am not using print 'hello', I am using the function properly).

Now it seems that even actual errors will not get caught, I type in:

```
prant('hello')
```

and it doesn't even register the misspelling of "print".

I have my project interpreter set to a version in miniconda environment, which I don't think would change anything, but even changing back to the default version will not get rid of the errors.

In the attached image you can see that "prant('hello') is simply not even registering as an unresolved reference now.

[image]

Comment: Neither of those worked, but after wiping every trace of pycharm off my hard drive and re-installing, everything seems to be peachy keen.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I "fixed" it, although I don't usually consider completely uninstalling the software, then having to delete settings from C:\Users\myname (which weren't caught by uninstall.exe), then making a new directory, creating new .py files and manually copy+pasting the contents of the old ones into it, a "fix".

But on the plus side, it actually does seem to find all my custom imports no problem, which it never did before, and now it actually catches unresolved references properly.  It's just a shame I had to go full nuclear just to make it happen.  My guess is I FUBAR'd the settings somehow and it kept persisting because those folders in C:\users\myname just wouldn't go away until I deleted them manually.

By the way, I tried both of the things in comments to the original post by downshift and neither of them worked.