# Pycharm “SDK seems invalid” when accessing interpreter from shared drive

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

My colleague and I both write simple python scripts on a shared drive, the projects are configured as a virtual environment with packages installed in the venv folder as usual.
In this case there is no need for version control. I simply want to access the projects in pycharm and use them in the same way he does.
If there is an easier system to achieve access to the same projects without worry about git I would love to know.

Anyway, to describe the error
When I try to execute his code using the project interpreter, I am hit with an error message

```
Unable to create process using 'C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py" --mode=client --port=51457'
```

When configuring the interpreter I get the error “Non-zero exit code (101)” with the output

```
Unable to create process using 'C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pip-20.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl\pip" install --no-index "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\setuptools-44.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl"'
```

I have attempted to setup the path by choosing python.exe in the venv folder of the project. This returns the above error, the interpreter settings say “Python packaging tools not found”.
I have two versions of python on my computer, standard python, and the versions packaged with anacondas. I have changed my system and environment path variables to only use the standard python with no luck.
The aforementioned “pydevconsole.py" is also in the specified path above.

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13988363) probably shows how to solve the problem.

Comment: I'd use proper version control, and perhaps Code With Me for realtime cooperative editing https://www.jetbrains.com/code-with-me/

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me, but try this...

- **First**:
  Go to Settings(click the gear icon in the top right corner, near the main button(with python sign).
- **Second**:
  Press project
  Then:
  click the gear icon, press "show all"
  then:
  click the + icon
- **Lastly**:
  click "System Interpreter(the python you installed should show in the "Interpreter" box, then click ok, then ok, ok